# Using css nth-child selector in freemarker

Tags: css-selectors, freemarker

How can I use css selector `nth-child` in a freemarker template? I want to draw a vertical line down the middle of a table of four columns.

Comment: This is purely a CSS question. FreeMarker just generates the HTML "source", it's the browser who renders it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although as `ddekany` says it's much better to do it via CSS you can do something like this using freemarker:

```
<table>
    <#list rows as row >
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td style="border-right:1px solid black"></td><#-- or class="bordered"-->
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
    </#list>
</table>
```